# AVR Assembly: What will be the address in the jmp and rjmp instructions?

Tags: assembly, binary, hex, avr

I've been given a code that goes like this:

*140 Back: jmp Forward*

*142 add*

*143 add*

.

. There are a total of 80 add instructions that go on like this

.

*222 lds*

*224 lds*

*226 lds*

.

. There are a total of 300 lds instructions that go on like this

.

*822 Forward: rjmp Back*

Which memory location's address will be stored in the jmp instruction in the 140th line and the rjmp instruction in the 822nd line? Will rjmp store address of 822-140 = *682* or 823-140 = *683* (given that PC+1).

Answer (score 1):

I think those numbers at the beginning of each line of this homework problem are not line numbers, but program counter values (i.e. addresses of words in flash, where each word is two bytes).

The `jmp` instruction stores absolute addresses, so the `jmp Forward` instruction will simply store the number **822**.

The `rjmp` instruction stores a number `k`, and causes the program counter (PC) to change to `PC + k + 1`.  So we have to solve for k, knowing that the PC is 822 initially and it must change to 140.  So we know 140 = 822 + k + 1, and therefore k = 140 - 822 - 1 = **-683**.